# unable to read property list from Info.plist

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, react-native

I'm trying to release an ios App using Xcode 11.3.1 after test it in a simulator it's work well but when I Archive I got this error!

> unable to read property list from file myApp/Info.plist: The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   (XCBUtil.PropertyListConversionError error 1.)

I don't change anything except add `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription & NSCameraUsageDescription` and as i say in simulator i don't get any issue

And change CFBundleVersion to 2 because i send an app previously to App store So that's it!

info.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
  <string>This app requires access to the photo library</string>
  <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
  <string>This app requires access to the camera</string>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>My App</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb1925390554405438553</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Editor</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>    <string>com.googleusercontent.apps.15678542661-g6ogpnitc5bldoficd2sgob9mrqcb295</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>2</string>
    <key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>192532214438553</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>3-Rap</string>
    <key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
    <string>ca-app-pub-1970767340436749~5956897205</string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fbapi20130214</string>
        <string>fbapi20130410</string>
        <string>fbapi20130702</string>
        <string>fbapi20131010</string>
        <string>fbapi20131219</string>
        <string>fbapi20140410</string>
        <string>fbapi20140116</string>
        <string>fbapi20150313</string>
        <string>fbapi20150629</string>
        <string>fbapi20160328</string>
        <string>fbauth</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UIAppFonts</key>
    <array>
        <string>Changa-Variable.ttf</string>
        <string>Feather.ttf</string>
        <string>Fontisto.ttf</string>
        <string>AntDesign.ttf</string>
        <string>Entypo.ttf</string>
        <string>EvilIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Brands.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Regular.ttf</string>
        <string>FontAwesome5_Solid.ttf</string>
        <string>Foundation.ttf</string>
        <string>Ionicons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialCommunityIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>MaterialIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>SimpleLineIcons.ttf</string>
        <string>Zocial.ttf</string>
        <string>Octicons.ttf</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>Launch Screen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: This is not really relevant but having an empty NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription is wrong.

Comment: @matt Is it for access to Location? if yes, i don't use any location permission in my app! I don't know why it's added!

Comment: @matt anyway i deleted it ;)

Comment: OK but we didn't solve your problem. If you can build and run, you should be able to archive. I can't understand why archiving would be different. Of course, with react, you are out of my field of understanding. :)

Comment: @matt Uh, it's very strange, it's work before I archiving it "when submitting the first v to App store" :\ is `CFBundleVersion & CFBundleShortVersionString` related?